# Lyx: xygraph and xymatrix in the same document

Tags: lyx, xymatrix

I need to write an article concerning knots, so I want to use the `knot` package in `xy`

Adding `\usepackage[knot]{xy}` to the preamble works fine, until I also draw diagrams (not knot diagrams) using `xymatrix`. Then Lyx says there is a clash because it automatically loads `xy` for `xymatrix` and it clashes with the preamble.

I tried adding "knot" to the document class options, and also tried adding `PackageOptions xy knot` in the local layout.

I also tried to change all Math Options to 'do not load' in order to specify my packages myself in the preamble.

Nothing works. I am using Lyx 2.3.0.

Please help.

Comment: Try to load everything: `\usepackage[all]{xy}`

Comment: Thank you - that is what Lyx does automatically when it encounters the xymatrix instance. Apparently, "all" does include "knot".

Comment: Can you please give us [a simple short but fully compilable example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows the problem?